# maven-scm-plugin 1.9.4 - too old to work with working copy

Tags: maven, svn

i am using 1.9.4 version of maven-scm-plugin,

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.4</version>
</plugin>
```

and i am getting an error

**svn: This client is too old to work with working copy 'E:\branches\project'; please get a newer Subversion client**

1. how do i know what is the svn version that maven-scm-plugin support or use...?
2. What is the maven-scm-plugin version that support for svn 1.6...?

Comment: Usually maven-scm-plugin will use the command client so i assume you have installed an older version of the svn command line clinet? Or have you configured to use the scm provider in java?

Comment: No i think ,maven-scm-plugin working individually (without svn client) ... I haven't setup svn command line client